# reduce space between portfolio thumbnails

Tags: css, wordpress, thumbnails, portfolio

I am using the Illustrator wordpress theme, and would like to

- reduce the space between my portfolio page thumbnails
- have my thumbnails display at full size.

**What I tried**

- I have used shortcode to set it to show 3 columns, and notice when I set it to 2 columns, the thumbnails show at full size, yet at 3 columns it reduces the thumnail size.
- Also, I have tried inspecting the thumbnails and notice no padding or border, so don't know how to reduce it further that way.

I would appreciate any help with the right CSS to make the thumbnails display at 100%, and possibly after that still reduce the space between the thumbnails, both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: You should provide some examples of the css and maybe some pictures from your thumbnails. And a link to your used theme, So is is really hard to help you

Answer (score 0):

Well it is hard to help you without a link or code but I'll stab at what might help you.

Try to see where the spacing is, it might not be on the thumbnails, it could be the image itself or some sort of nested containers. Once you find that padding/margin you can adjust it, it has to be somewhere. If you want to skip that and have some confusing code, add negative margins to the image thumbnails themselves. margin: -5px; for example.

To make the thumbnails there full size

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

now if you want to enforce a size, just add them to a container and set the size of the container

```
<div style="max-width:200px;">
    <img src="#" />
</div>
```